# How to access Kafka service in Github action?

Tags: github, apache-kafka, continuous-integration

Running the most basic test using a Kafka client results in the error `NoBrokersAvailable`.
My Github workflow setup:

```
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      zoo_keeper:
        image: bitnami/zookeeper
        ports:
          - 2181:2181
        env:
          ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: yes
        options: >-
          --health-cmd "echo mntr | nc -w 2 -q 2 localhost 2181"
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
      kafka:
        image: bitnami/kafka
        ports:
          - 9092:9092
        options: >-
          --health-cmd "kafka-broker-api-versions.sh --version"
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
        env:
          KAFKA_CFG_KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zookeeper:2181"
          ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: yes
          KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS: "CLIENT://:9092,INTERNAL://:9093"
          KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: "CLIENT://localhost:9092,INTERNAL://kafka:9093"
          KAFKA_CFG_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: "CLIENT:PLAINTEXT,INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT"
          KAFKA_CFG_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
    ...
    steps:
      - name: test
        ...
        run: pytest
```

Running the same setup locally (on `docker-windows`) and running the tests locally (not from a container) works and successfully connects to Kafka.

My tests use `KAFKA_URL=localhost:9092` and run on Github runner host (not a container).
In another test, I successfully connect to `postgres` (using localhost as the hostname).
I am sure it's some misconfiguration, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The main reason why your setup is not working is probably because your zookeeper service is named `zoo_keeper` with an underscore and you configure kafka to connect to `zookeeper:2181`.

If I change the name of your zookeeper service to `zookeeper` and use the following environment variables for the kafka service, it works for me:

```
KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: yes
KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following custom [GitHub Action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/kafka-kraft) that will create a Kafka (KRaft) Broker in your GitHub Actions pipelines.

You can then connect to it using either of the following listeners:

- `localhost:9092`
- `$kafka_runner_address:9093` (*kafka_runner_address* is an environment variable created by the above custom github action).

Just update your GitHub workflow to include the below (*You can specify the kafka version you want to use [>3.3] and the topics/partitions you want to create too*) :

```
  - name: Run Kafka KRaft Broker
    uses: spicyparrot/kafka-kraft-action@v1.1.0
    with:
      kafka-version: "3.6.1"
      kafka-topics: "foo,1,bar,3"

  - name:  Run PyTests
    run: pytest
```

Then in your pytests, just configure your `bootstrap.servers` to point towards `localhost:9092` or `$kafka_runner_address:9093`, for e.g.:

```
import os
from confluent_kafka import Producer

kafka_endpoint = os.getenv("kafka_runner_address")

producer_config = {
  'bootstrap.servers': (kafka_endpoint + ':9093') if kafka_endpoint else 'localhost:9092' 
}

# Instantiate a producer
producer = Producer(producer_config)
```

[GitHub repo](https://github.com/spicyparrot/kafka-kraft-action)

[Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/apachekafka/comments/1bfhjxf/kafka_in_github_actions/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Hope this helps!